# Is there any way to build a command line interface for an already existing windows application (which doesn't have a CLI)?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I only have the application and don't have the access to the source code. I want to build a command line interface so that the application can take some inputs (images for example) and process them to produce some results.

Comment: Just curious, what OS? How do you supply inputs to the application now? Are there buttons you click? Text boxes to fill up? etc.?

Comment: Thanks. It's a windows application. Yes there are buttons to click. I tried with autohotkey but no luck till now (I am also a noob in autohotkey).

Comment: You may want to look at [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Comment: Thanks! Are AutoHotKey and AutoIt similar or very different from each other?

Comment: [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is a set of python modules to automate the Microsoft Windows GUI. At it’s simplest it allows you to send mouse and keyboard actions to windows dialogs and controls.